# why maxDrawdown function in package PerformanceAnalytics returns wrong result?

Tags: r, xts, performanceanalytics

I want to use the `maxDrawdown` function in package PerformanceAnalytics to calculate maximum drawdown, but find that it always returns zero (which is not).

I use `maxDrawdown` like this

```
> maxDrawdown(my.xts)
[1] 0
```

My xts is like this:

```
> my.xts
           value
2004-06-16 4.150
2004-06-17 4.225
2004-06-18 4.025
2004-06-21 4.000
2004-06-23 4.425
2004-06-24 4.450
2004-06-25 4.400
2004-06-28 4.325
2004-06-29 4.325
2004-06-30 4.300
2004-07-02 4.350
2004-07-06 4.400
2004-07-07 4.275
2004-07-08 4.100
2004-07-09 4.075
2004-07-12 4.000
2004-07-13 4.025
2004-07-14 3.800
2004-07-15 3.675
2004-07-16 3.700
```

str(my.xts) returns

```
An ‘xts’ object on 2004-06-16/2004-07-16 containing:
  Data: num [1:20, 1] 4.15 4.22 4.03 4 4.42 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "value"
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ:-
  xts Attributes:--
 NULL
```

And, I write a function to verify

```
my.mmd <- function(v) {
  max(1 - v / cummax(v))
}
```

The results is not zero.

```
> my.mmd(my.xts$value)
[1] 0.1741573
```

Why does the maxDrawdown returns 0 ?

---

I construct a case using at http://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/maximum-drawdown-mdd.asp.

```
other.xts <- xts(c(500,750,400,600,350, 800), Sys.Date() + 1:6)
maxDrawdown(other.xts) # --> here still returns 0!
my.mmd(other.xts)  # -> my function returns 0.5333333, seems right.
```

Maybe I use `maxDrawdown` function in a wrong way! But I look through the doc again () and still cannot get it. Am I miss something in using this function ?

Comment: There is no `maxDrawdown` in `xts`. Do you mean `maxDrawdown` in `PerformanceAnalytics`?

Comment: sorry.. yes , i mean PerformanceAnalytics.

Comment: Using `data(edhec)` and `x <- edhec[,"Funds of Funds"]`, `maxDrawdown(x)` gives `0.2059145`, while your function (`my.mmd(x)`) gives `2.416092`.

Answer (score 4):

Your xts object contains Price data versus Returns which is why you are getting `maxDrawdown = 0`

For example:

```
 # Using Prices instead of returns to calculate Drawdowns
a <- Ad(getSymbols("AAPL", auto.assign = FALSE))

head(a)
           AAPL.Adjusted
2007-01-03      11.19449
2007-01-04      11.44295
2007-01-05      11.36147
2007-01-08      11.41757
2007-01-09      12.36603
2007-01-10      12.95782

maxDrawdown(head(a))
[1] 0
```

Now using Returns:

```
# Nice wrapper to calculate returns via PerformanceAnalytics
ret <-CalculateReturns(head(a), "discrete")

> head(ret)
           AAPL.Adjusted
2007-01-03            NA
2007-01-04   0.022195570
2007-01-05  -0.007121151
2007-01-08   0.004938271
2007-01-09   0.083070194
2007-01-10   0.047855606
> maxDrawdown(ret)
[1] 0.007121151
```